# Why is the size given by lsblk different from that of lsblk -b

Tags: usb, partitioning, devices

I have a disk that appear with 134G with the command `lsblk` but a higher number with `lsblk -b` (about 10G more)

**Why do I have a different size with lsblk and lsblk -b?**

```
#lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM          SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  134G  0 disk 
[...]
# lsblk -b
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM          SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  147035272690  0 disk 
[...]
```

Comment: Converting the bytes to GB, I got 136.93GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the difference isn't that great. Remember that gigabytes, megabytes etc, are multiples of 1024 and not 1000. So, a megabyte is 1024<sup>2</sup> and a gigabyte is 1024<sup>3</sup>.

Many programming languages give convenient [shift operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Shift-Operators), that let you convert between mega, giga, kilo and other -bytes. Here, using Perl, we can see that your two values are actually not that different:

```
## How many bytes is 134G?
$ perl -le 'print 134<<30'
143881404416

## How many gigabytes is 147035272690 bytes?
$ perl -le 'print 147035272690>>30'
136
```

There still is a discrepancy of 2G between the numbers, but it's nowhere near 10G. I don't really know where that difference comes from. I suspect that there are rounding steps involved (probably using a [floor](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/floor.3.html) function), but I don't know the details.

Comment: Actually, doing the math manually, it's more like 137GB. (136.93)

Comment: @AndroidDev yes, but they're probably using a shift operator and that discards fractional parts.

Comment: > Remember that gigabytes, megabytes etc, are multiples of 1024 and not 1000

This is not universal, disk vendors usually respect SI prefixes. Only the terms gibibyte (GiB), mebibyte (MiB), etc. are unambiguous. With “GB”, “MB”, etc., unfortunately you never know whether the author meant 1024 or 1000, unless the author clarified it.

Comment: @Ruud um OK? Not entirely sure why you're making that point here, of course they're not universal, that's the whole point. In this case, however, the OP had been counting using multiples of 1000 and they _should_ have been using 1024.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference as you think.
1 GB = 1,073,741,824 Bytes
Now let us convert your 134 GB to bytes.
134GB = (134)x(1,073,741,824) = 143881404416 bytes

Comment: Careful! 1G**b** (Giga**bit**) = 1/8 of 1G**B** (Giga**byte**)!